# Elements of G/H have finite order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I need help in this problem.

Let $G = \mathbb{Z}$ x $\mathbb{Z}$, and let $H$ be the subgroup of $G$ generated by the pair $(2,4)$ . Which elements of $G/H$ have finite order.

Comment: Have you written up the conditions for an element in the quotient to be $0$? Have you written up what is means for a multiple of an element in the quotient to be $0$?

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

$$(a,b)+H\in\left(\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\right)/H\;\;\text{has finite order}\;\;\iff\;\exists\,n\in\Bbb Z\;,\;n\neq 0\,,\;s.t.\;\;n(a,b)\in H\iff$$

$$(na,nb)=(2m,4m)\;,\;\;\text{for some}\;\;m\in\Bbb Z\iff \begin{cases}na=2m\\nb=4m\end{cases}$$

For example, the element $\;(1,3)+H\;$ cannot have finite order as then for some $\;n,m\in\Bbb Z\;$ we'd have $\;n=2m\;,\;3n=4m\iff\;3n=2n\ldots\;$

Now, check the element $\;(5,10)+H\;$ **does** have finite order (and it is two, btw).

Can you generalize now?